# controller not found in catalog->products in prestashop

Tags: controller, admin, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i'm trying to add new products in categories.. i have created two categories indoor products and outdoor products. these two categories are showing in menu bar. i need to add products for these two categories..

when i selected catalog->products it showing "controller not found "

help me with this problem..

i have one doubt in this problem "here new products are not adding in prestashop but how demo products are added in it"

i'm stuck with this problem please help me to get out of this

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange. you shouldn't have any errors on new installation. 
Check all file & folder permissions and you can try reinstall your prestashop once again.
Hopes that help.